# how to push additional required files to the app directory?

Tags: android, c++, c++14, adb, file-transfer

I am new to Android Development , I was googling for this answer , but a lot of things are just how to upload music and stuff to your device.

**Some information**

I have a an app that compiles to c++ which will run on the device when I push it with gradlew installDebug . The problem is that I want to add some dependencies that are rather large making about 1G in file space.

I noticed that I cannot write at all to the /data/app/app-name directory when I tried to use adb push files.

Is there a way to have them moved to there during the install or how should this be handled? Keep in mind my app is written in C++ and used the ndk-builder to crosscompile .

**In short:**

Ideally, I would like the user to have the ability to just have all the files he needs when the application is installed. How can/should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is you can add files to your /data/app/res/ folder upon install , but it has to be small I think less than 100MB.

You can just user permission tag to the manafest and store the data in **/sdcard/Yourcreatedfolder** then access it like any other directory in C.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pvallet.com.github.hello_sdl2">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"    
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"    


    >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloSDL2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"


        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"   />
</manifest>
```